# How do I use regex to do some Javascript string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that begins and ends with the table row tag `<tr>...</tr>`. There are multiple `<td>`s inside this, that take the form:

```
<td class="someClass">TextIWant TextI Do NOtWant</td><td><img src='green.png'></td>
<td class="someClass">TextIWant TextI Do NOtWant</td><td><img src='blue.png'></td>
```

What I'm looking to do, is look at the color.png, and add a class to the td, and trim some of the text inside the td. The final output should be something like:

```
<td class="someClass green">TextIWant</td>
<td class="someClass blue">TextIWant</td>
```

How can I do this with regular expressions?

Comment: They're *strings*? That isn't HTML in the DOM?

Comment: so how do you tell the difference between the text that you want and the text that you don't want?

Comment: You could definitely avoid using regex for most of this - get the source of the image, strip the extension; append that to the class list of the previous cell; use a regex to strip out the unwanted text.

Comment: Do you have a regex that you think should work, and doesn't? We are more willing to help fix your code than to write the code for you.

Comment: Do you plan to perform your replacements with javascript in the browser?

Comment: This is generally much easier to do and more reliable by creating DOM elements (let the browser's HTML parser do all the parsing work for you) and then use DOM search/manipulation.  You don't ever have to make it visible in your page to use DOM manipulation.

Comment: If all the img src tags are going to be a png with the same name as the class you want to add, you don't need regex.  Just take the src tag and chop off the '.png'.  As far as trimming the text inside the td tag I think we need a bit more specifics.

Comment: The text that I don't want doesn't have a pattern. It is always the same text that keeps repeating in each td.

Yes, I was hoping to use JS to do the replacements with string.replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to provide a lot more details about what you need to do, but the best course of action would be to use a DOM parser and JavaScript has a very nice one built in (IE8- is not supported).

```
// Select all odd `td` nodes and iterate over them
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(odd)"),
function (elem) {
    // Get the immediately following sibling (with the img)
    var imgTd = elem.nextSibling;
    // Get the color from the <img>
    elem.className += ' ' + imgTd.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src")
        .replace('.png', '');
    // Remove the sibling
    imgTd.parentNode.removeChild(imgTd);
    // Update the initial elements text to remove the undesired text
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace("TextI Do NOtWant", "");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9vrK/

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I need. I will try it out, and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Id do this with jquery, something like:

```
var td;
var img;
var color;
 $('img').each(function(){
   img=$(this);
   td = img.closest('td').prev();
   color = img.attr('src').split('.')[0]
     td.html('the image is '+color+'.png').addClass(color);
 });
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/QHkbe/2